# Android ListView smooth scroll to top not working as intended

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am building for Android 2.2+

I am using `ListView` method `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` to scroll back to top of the list. It works most of the time but if some of the list items height becomes variable then `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` stops when it reaches longer list items.

Is it a bug? or am I doing something wrong?

here is the sample `Activity` code which produce the issue:

```
public class SimpleListViewActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView mainListView ;
    private Button btnScrollToTop ;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

         // some test data
         String[] planets = new String[] {    "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40", 
                                  "Mercury","Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                                  "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10",
                                  "Jupiter", "Saturn","Uranus",
                                  "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40",
                                  "Neptune",
                                  "Ceres",
                                  "Pluto",
                                  "Haumea",
                                  "Makemake",
                                  "Eris"
                                };  
         ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
         planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

         listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
         mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );    


         //scroll to top
         btnScrollToTop = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_scroll_to_top);
         btnScrollToTop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                mainListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
              }

        });
    }
}
```

xml main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_scroll_to_top"
      android:text="Scroll To Top"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp" 
     />

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:id="@+id/mainListView">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list row layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use view.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0,0) instead of view.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Answer (score 0):

Found out it's known bug with Android ICS and Jelly bean. 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37278

I have the following workaround for now. It works but not ideal as there is noticeable velocity change while scrolling

code to scroll to top:

```
ScrollToTopListener scrollToTopListener=new ScrollToTopListener();
mainListView.setOnScrollListener(scrollToTopListener);
scrollToTopListener.scrollToTop();
messagesList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

ScrollToTopListener class:

```
public  class ScrollToTopListener implements OnScrollListener {

     private boolean scrollToTop=false;

     public  ScrollToTopListener(){

     }


     public void scrollToTop(){
         scrollToTop=true;
     }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


        if(scrollToTop){
           if(firstVisibleItem != 0) {
               view.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
               }  
               else {
                       scrollToTop=false;
               }
        }

    }

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
      if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
         scrollToTop=false;
     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ListView.setSelection(position) to scroll from your desired position